# Tests keep using "production" database even after I change sqlalchemy_database_uri in pytest fixture

Tags: flask, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I have **flask** application that I am using to get familiar with the **flask-sqlalchemy** lib and testing using **Pytest** with fixtures.

I am trying to overwrite the sqlalchemy_database_uri in the app configuration in my test fixtures. But the problem is that when I run them, my **tests seem to be working with the "production" database rather than with an ephemeral one**. The test record I created for test via fixtures are all in the database that I create in the app initialization.

When I run the test in the example below using `pytest` from the root folder in that structure. The tests are collected ok, run and pass as expected. But after running the tests a new database called `hello.db` has been created in the `instance` folder. What I am trying to do is that the tests use a sqlite database in memory that disapears after the tests run.

How do I go about **writing/configuring my tests so that I use an ephemeral sqlite database in memory that is only used for those tests**?

```
# Folder structure
.
├── mini_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── config.py
│   └── models.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_all.py
```

```
## app.py

from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from mini_app import config

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(cfg= None):
    if cfg is None:
        cfg = config.Config()
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(cfg)

    # Init_apps
    db.init_app(app)

    @app.route("/square")
    def square():
        """A view which uses no templates and no database."""
        number = int(request.args.get("number", 0))
        return str(number ** 2)

    return app
```

```
## config.py

class Config:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///hello.db"
```

```
## models.py

from mini_app.app import db

class Author(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "authors"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
```

```
## test_all.py

import pytest

import  mini_app.app
import  mini_app.models

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    # Prepare before your test
    app = mini_app.app.create_app()
    app.config["TESTING"] = True
    app.testing = True
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite://"

    with app.test_client() as client:
        with app.app_context():
            mini_app.app.db.create_all()
            author1 = mini_app.models.Author(id=1, name="foo")
            mini_app.app.db.session.add(author1)
            mini_app.app.db.session.commit()
        # Give control to the test
        yield client

        # Cleanup after the test run.
        # ... nothing here, for this simple example


def test_square(client):
    rv = client.get("/square?number=8")
    assert b"64" == rv.data
```

Comment: Any progress here?