# PyTest isn't changing database strings in Flask app

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 2 databases set in .env:

1: `DATABASE_URI`

2: `TEST_DB_URI`

--

When running my test suite with pytest, all tests return with a duplicate entry error; test file provided below as an example.

`sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 'test@example.com' for key 'users.email'")`

The specific issue is DB #1 has this user created, meanwhile DB #2 does not.

Flask config **is not** using DB #2 when executing the test as intended.

--

#tests/`__`init`__` .py

```
import os
import pytest
from app import app, db
from models.user import User

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    # Configure variables
    app.config["TESTING"] = True
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("TEST_DB_URI")

    # Create test_client
    with app.test_client() as client:
        with app.app_context():
            db.create_all()
            # Create a test user
            user = User(
                email="test@example.com",
                password="test_password",
            )
            # Add test user and commit to DB
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()

        with app.app_context():
            db.session.remove()
            db.drop_all()
        yield client
```

#tests/test_login.py

```
import pytest
from tests import client

def test_login_success(client):
    response = client.post(
        "/auth/login", data={"email": "test@example.com", "password": "test_password"}
    )
    assert response.status_code == 302
```

#app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate

# create the app
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/static")
# import Flask app configuration
app.config.from_pyfile("config.py")
# create the SQLALchemy extension
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
# Create login_manager
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
```

and

#config.py

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SESSION_KEY']
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URI']
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
"""Flask App configuration."""

# General Config
ENVIRONMENT = "development"
FLASK_APP = "app"
FLASK_DEBUG = True
TESTING = True
```

--
This is question is related to / duplicate of unresolved question: [Tests keep using "production" database even after I change sqlalchemy_database_uri in pytest fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74336484/tests-keep-using-production-database-even-after-i-change-sqlalchemy-database-u)

I've tried to set the following variable when configuring my client pytest fixture. This doesn't appear to be getting respected when executing the test suite. I don't know why this is.

`app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("TEST_DB_URI")`

Comment: Can you try reducing code to something close to a minimal reproduction?

And you can solve your italics issues by using the backtick character `__like__ _this_` using "`"

Comment: Also, why are you sure that these aren't legitimate failures? If you've run your test once but forgot to remove an entry while developing your test, then this would be a legitimate test failure, no?

Comment: @justhecuke thanks for the tip re: back tick. I'll reduce code tomorrow as I'm responding from mobile. On your second question, they relate to two different databases, the errors refer to data stored in "production" db whereas I'm attempting to use a separate testing db.

Comment: Reduced code, hopefully its enough?

Comment: As a general rule, you should try to make a minimal reproduction. Right now, it'd be a bit complicated for me to actually try and setup something to see if what I would suggest would work.

Comment: I haven't taken a deep look into things but there are a couple of red flags for you to look into: (1) in your `tests` module's fixture, print out `app.config` before and after your modification and see if it sticks. In your test print out the same if you can. (2) why is your test re-using an existing Flask rather than making a new one for the test? It's not good test design. (3) why did you put the test fixture into the `__init__.py` file? it's not a good idea to put things into that file that are unrelated to module API/visibility issues because it is treated specially and has odd behaviors.

Comment: @justhecuke thanks. I'm working on this project with another dev. Changes we've made: (1) Added a conftest.py for the test fixture. (2) We're not using a test-db; we've realized this is not needed as the records are removed after every test session. We've got a test suite running now with more logical conditions; thank you for your ongoing support to rectify this issue.